# jQuery datepicker with current year - 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have jquery datepicker like so

```
 $birth.datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $(this).parent().find("label#error").html("");
        $gender.focus();
    },
        yearRange: '1950:2006',
        changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,           
    showOtherMonths: true,          
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: new Date(2006,01,01),
    });
```

I am trying to modify this code so it will take the current year and subtract it by 10 like so

```
$birth.datepicker({
        var currentYear = new Date();
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $(this).parent().find("label#error").html("");
        $gender.focus();
    },
        yearRange: '1950:document.write(currentYear.getFullYear() - 10)',
        changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,           
    showOtherMonths: true,          
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        defaultDate: new Date(2006,01,01),
    });
```

The code above this does not work, it breaks my datepicker....is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Note you should also change the default date to be 10 years ago...

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
yearRange: '1950:document.write(currentYear.getFullYear() - 10)',
```

to:

```
yearRange: '1950:-10',
```

That will set the yearRange from 1950 to 10 years less than the current year.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6aaFb/)**

From the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) for the yearRange option:

> The range of years displayed in the year drop-down: either relative to
>   today's year ("-nn:+nn"), relative to the currently selected year
>   ("c-nn:c+nn"), absolute ("nnnn:nnnn"), or combinations of these
>   formats ("nnnn:-nn").

Answer (score 0):

No dude no.

Do all the variable calculations outside the `datepicker` function call.

This code **cannot** run.

Use this

```
var year = (new Date()).getFullYear() - 10
```

and in the datepicker initializer

```
yearRange: "1950:" + year,
```

That should be enough

Comment: good answer, though jQuery already does this for you if you put a `+` or `-` in front of the year string.

Comment: I am guessing you meant jquery.datepicker does it, not jquery really, right? ;)